# What does a polynomial function's increasing and decreasing interval mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Now I know that smarter and more interesting question were asked over here, but bear with me. 
When someone says,"the increasing interval of this polynomial function is (-infinity, 4)," when does it ACTUALLY start to increase? More clearly, at which point in -infinity (if that makes sense) does this function increase?

Comment: That statements here simply means that given any two points $x_1, x_2\in (-\infty, 4)$ with $x_1<x_2$, then this implies that $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.

Comment: This piece of information just tells you that as long as x is less than four then the function is increasing (look at the comment above this)...... so there is NO specific point in which it starts to increase.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that a function $f(x)$ monotonically increases in the range $(-\infty,4)$. This also implies that $f'(x)>0$ for all real values $x\in (-\infty,4)$. You may also choose to think that as you go in the $-x$ direction from $4$, the function always decreases.